# Find third and fourth coordinate of a rectangle knowing two coordinates and width

Tags: geometry

Supposed we have a rectangle ABCD. We have two coordinates of A=(x1,y1) and B=(X2,y2) and its width=W. I want to find the other two coordinates C and D.
[image]

I know I might be able to calculate the third coordinate using `Thales's theorem` as follows.

`AO` and `OC` are a circle's radius which in that circle B and D are valid point. So I need to solve the following equation.

`(x1-ox)^2 + (y1-oy)^2 = AO^2` and we have `AO^2 = w^2 + L^2` and `L` is `distance` between `A` and `B`.
So I was thinking maybe there is any already solved equation out there to easily find the D and C coordinates.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define the vector $v = (v_x, v_y) = (x_2 - x_1, y_2 - y_1) $
2. Normalize $v$, i.e define $v_N= (v_{Nx}, v_{Ny}) = \dfrac{v}{\|v\|} $
3. Find the vector $u$ that points $90^\circ$ counter clockwise from the direction of $v_N$, this vector is given by $u_N = (u_{Nx}, u_{Ny}) = (- v_{Ny}, v_{Nx} ) $
4. Now points $C $ and $D$ are given by (two solutions)

   $ C = B \pm w \cdot u_N $ and $D = A \pm w \cdot u_N $

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain part 2 and 3? I want to implement it in code and got confused there a bit

Comment: Vector $v_N = \dfrac{ (x_2 - x_1, y_2 - y_1) }{\sqrt{ (x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2 } }$

Comment: For vector $u_N$ , swap the coordinates of $v_N$ and change the sign of the first coordinates, so $(v_{Nx}, v_{Ny})$ becomes $(-v_{Ny}, v_{Nx})$

Answer (score 1):

Sketch of the solution:

- Find the perpendicular direction to the line passing through $A$ and $B$.
- Take the point $A$ and add $W$ in the direction of the perpendicular line found previously.
- To find out $C$, use the equation:
  \begin{align*}
  \frac{A + C}{2} = \frac{B + D}{2}
  \end{align*}
- Notice there are two solutions to the proposed problem.